# Azure Functio on respond alerts

Tags: azure-functions, azure-monitoring

I am planning to create Function app to parse alert data and using that parsed data to respond alert. When alerts are created in Log Analytics, monitoringService are defined as Log Analytics. This leads to that affected resources e.g Virtual Machines have no additional information about it on the alert(like subscription id, resource group). This make a bit hard to e.g cast command `Restart-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup11" -Name "VirtualMachine07"` because alert data do not contain that information about resource and thus, I can't parse and use it as variable.

We can use this schema [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-common-schema-definitions#monitoringservice--log-analytics) as example were, we can see that resourceId is pointing to laws, not the affected resources.  From this information I should figure out ways to save affected resouces subscription and resource data to variables so I can use them later.

```
{
  "alertContext": {
    "SearchQuery": "Perf | where ObjectName == \"Processor\" and CounterName == \"% Processor Time\" | summarize AggregatedValue = avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 5m), Computer",
    "SearchIntervalStartTimeUtc": "3/22/2019 1:36:31 PM",
    "SearchIntervalEndtimeUtc": "3/22/2019 1:51:31 PM",
    "ResultCount": 2,
    "LinkToSearchResults": "https://portal.azure.com/#Analyticsblade/search/index?_timeInterval.intervalEnd=2018-03-26T09%3a10%3a40.0000000Z&_timeInterval.intervalDuration=3600&q=Usage",
    "LinkToFilteredSearchResultsUI": "https://portal.azure.com/#Analyticsblade/search/index?_timeInterval.intervalEnd=2018-03-26T09%3a10%3a40.0000000Z&_timeInterval.intervalDuration=3600&q=Usage",
    "LinkToSearchResultsAPI": "https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/workspaceID/query?query=Heartbeat&timespan=2020-05-07T18%3a11%3a51.0000000Z%2f2020-05-07T18%3a16%3a51.0000000Z",
    "LinkToFilteredSearchResultsAPI": "https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/workspaceID/query?query=Heartbeat&timespan=2020-05-07T18%3a11%3a51.0000000Z%2f2020-05-07T18%3a16%3a51.0000000Z",
    "SeverityDescription": "Warning",
    "WorkspaceId": "12345a-1234b-123c-123d-12345678e",
    "SearchIntervalDurationMin": "15",
    "AffectedConfigurationItems": [
      "INC-Gen2Alert"
    ],
    "SearchIntervalInMinutes": "15",
    "Threshold": 10000,
    "Operator": "Less Than",
    "Dimensions": [
      {
        "name": "Computer",
        "value": "INC-Gen2Alert"
      }
    ],
    "SearchResults": {
      "tables": [
        {
          "name": "PrimaryResult",
          "columns": [
            {
              "name": "$table",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "name": "Computer",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "name": "TimeGenerated",
              "type": "datetime"
            }
          ],
          "rows": [
            [
              "Fabrikam",
              "33446677a",
              "2018-02-02T15:03:12.18Z"
            ],
            [
              "Contoso",
              "33445566b",
              "2018-02-02T15:16:53.932Z"
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "dataSources": [
      {
        "resourceId": "/subscriptions/a5ea55e2-7482-49ba-90b3-60e7496dd873/resourcegroups/test/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/test",
        "tables": [
          "Heartbeat"
        ]
      }
    ],
  "IncludedSearchResults": "True",
  "AlertType": "Metric measurement"
  }
}
```

What would be good chooses to get around this problem so that I could somehow get to know what are affected resources subscription id and resource group so i can use AZ command to them? I know how to parse alert data and se it to variables but are having hard time to get e.g vm information out.

Comment: Have you gone through this link https://www.fourmoo.com/2020/02/19/how-to-configure-azure-function-app-notifications-for-errors/

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru-MT Had not seen that but really do not help me